# escape sequences are not working in php

Tags: php

if im not wrong `\n` representation means that a newline as `<br>` .But when i use `<br>` or another tags they work properly but escape sequences.

example

```
echo "write somethings<br>";
echo "about coding";
```

above example works fine but when i try to use escape sequences none of them are not working

```
echo "write something\n";
echo "about coding";
```

it's just an example for newline character and the other escaping characters dont work as `\n`.What is the real logic on this case?

Answer (score 1):

`\n` and other similar escape sequences are not part of HTML. You should use HTML escape sequences. These can be found here: http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

So only your `<br>` tag works but `\n` is not

Answer (score 1):

No, this is an example of HTML rules.

Putting `\n` in a PHP string and then outputting it as HTML will put a new line character in the HTML *source code*. It's just line pressing return when writing raw HTML.

HTML puts no special meaning on the new line character (at least outside of script elements and elements with various non-default values of the CSS [white-space property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)) and treats it like any other white space character.

`<br>`, on the other hand, is a line break element (but usually an indication that you should be using a block level element around the content instead).

Answer (score 1):

HTML ignores carriage return and linefeed characters, treating them as [whitespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.1). If you want to use display a string formatted with `"\n"` you can use [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br) to convert it, e.g.

```
echo nl2br("this is on\ntwo lines");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this in the browser it wont work : browser knows only HTML for display (`<br>`) but not escape like `\n` or `\r`